# DNN project build and debugging

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have public_html folder with me which is DNN application. All folders are placed inside this html_folder. when i am trying to build the solution in Visual Studio 2010, it's giving build error. Can anyone please tell me how can i build the solution and debugging the same

Answer (score 0):

They way I usually go about this is to use Chris Hammond's Christoc [templates](http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/2) for Visual Studio which can be installed as an extension. Tools > Extensions and Updates and search for dotnetnuke. This way you can develop custom DNN modules for any DNN instance. The templates include documentation for setting up your dev environment correctly. So instead of trying to build/debug your entire DNN project, just ensure your modules are in the DesktopModules folder in your DNN instance and make use of DNN's built in API's to do your development work.

Building these templates in release mode would create installable modules for your DNN instance.

Once installed you can debug. Debugging requires you to attach the DNN process - Debug > Attach to Process > Show all processes > Select w3wp.exe and Attach. Which will attach to the IIS instance running your DNN environment.